# Using WebAssembly inside chrome sandbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors, sandbox, webassembly

I have a chrome extension that includes a complicated function `comp_func(data)` which takes a lot of CPU by performing many bitwise operations. Because of that, I'm trying to use WebAssembly.
After many tries I came to a conclusion that due to permissions issues I need to use this function inside a sandbox.

Right now I'm trying to follow [this WebAssembly tutorial](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/06/getting-started-with-web-assembly) and [this Sandbox example](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval)  as an "hello world" example for my problem.

The WebAssembly files includes: `index.js` and `index.wasm`,
The sandbox files is: `sandbox.html`,
`page.js` is the code of the extension that need to perform `comp_func(data)` and is using `postMessage` as a way to communicate to `sandbox.html`.
`background.html` is the background file of the extension.

This is what I have so far:

**manifest.json**

```
   "sandbox": {
     "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
   },
```

**background.js**

```
<script src="page.js"></script>
<iframe id="theFrame" src="sandbox.html" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

**sandbox.html**

```
<html>
      <body>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script>
        var result = _roll_dice(); //the function of the WebAssembly
        console.log('results! ', result);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

So, right now the extension is calling `sandbox.html` who in turn loading `index.js`, but then I get the error:

> Failed to load
>   chrome-extension://**index.wasm**: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque
>   response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
>   fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

From what I understand, `index.js` is calling `index.wasm` and because I'm inside a sandbox there is a problem with **CORS** permissions.
Is someone know what is the solution in this case?

Comment: What exactly was the permissions issue? If it was caused by inline code in script tag, simply use a separate js file. Try also an [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API) that uses a different approach.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank for the reply! I also tried to do it from the MDN tutorial with no success. If i'm trying to do it outside the sandbox I get this error: "Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.compile(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder"

Comment: Maybe Chrome doesn't support wasm in extensions, but only from https? You can try to "serve" it by using a Service Worker inside your extension. Also consider asking on https://crbug.com or [chromium-extensions-announce](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/chromium-extensions).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

WebAssembly modules are typically loaded via HTTP from JavaScript, however, there are other ways to include them in your code. You could for example base64 encode your WebAssembly binary and include that as a string. Or, you could use a build tool such as rollup to do that for you:

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-wasm

This allows you to reference a wasm file as an import:

```
import wasm from './sample.wasm';

sample({ ...imports }).then(({ instance }) => {
  console.log(instance.exports.main())
})
```

However, when built with rollup it will be base64 encoded and inlined.